Expo command is failing for submitting the app to TestFlight
The eas build -p iOS command fails to run through with an error message in the logs shown below; running npx expo build:ios works without an issue though.
logs
I have tried altering the ./src/... path but haven't found a solution.

Please prefer including the plain text logs directly copied to the question part without links. This way the helpful answerers would not need to click any links but could see the relevant thing directly. Also it is not guaranteed that the link will always be there.

It turns out that a developer on the team had added that file to .gitignore and thus expo couldn't find it, the simple fix for now was to remove the file from .gitignore.

if you are sure the files really exists try changing the interpreter, as of my knowledge

Ok, I don't quite understand what you mean with "interpreter", in this context?

what code editor are you using if vscode then "click on the search input at the top" select "show and run commands" and find "python: select interpreter" and change to the recommended python interpreter

and when you get to the main coding environment use command prompt just use the pattern it should lead

@SHADRACHNICHOLASBITRUS This question is about react-native which is a  JavaScript (or TypeScript) framework. Nothing to do with Python.

thought as much, but i still recommended you try similar direction on the side of your language, because i've had such issue in my course of work before

You can post this as a comment on the question instead of answer.

thank you for the directives, my apologies

Seems like awsconfig file may have some module that is not recognized in node_modules.
Typically I have seen this type of error if new library is added and forgot to do npm install before.
